# How attach NServiceBus to SQL Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nservicebus

I try to use NServiceBus with SQL Server as transport in my project. It is an ASP.NET MVC application. I downloaded test example here https://docs.particular.net/samples/sqltransport-nhpersistence/ and use endpoint configuration as described in this example.

Code for configurate endpoint:

```
var hibernateConfig = new Configuration();
hibernateConfig.DataBaseIntegration(x =>
            {
                x.ConnectionStringName = "NServiceBus/Persistence";
                x.Dialect<MsSql2012Dialect>();
            });

hibernateConfig.SetProperty("default_schema", "sender");

var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("Samples.SQLNHibernateOutboxEF.Sender");
NServiceBus.Logging.LogManager.Use<DefaultFactory>().Directory(Server.MapPath("~/").Trim('/') + "/Logs");

endpointConfiguration.LicensePath(Server.MapPath("~/").Trim('\\').Trim('/') + "/License.xml");
endpointConfiguration.UseSerialization<JsonSerializer>();
endpointConfiguration.EnableInstallers();

#region SenderConfiguration
var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<SqlServerTransport>();
transport.DefaultSchema("sender");
transport.UseSchemaForQueue("error", "dbo");
transport.UseSchemaForQueue("audit", "dbo");

endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<NHibernatePersistence>();
endpointConfiguration.EnableOutbox();

#endregion

var endpoint = await Endpoint.Start(endpointConfiguration).ConfigureAwait(false);

var news = new SendNewsEvent
            {
                NewsId = 1,
                SendToAll = true
            };

var r = endpoint.Publish(news ).ConfigureAwait(false);

await nBusEndpoint.Stop().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Bad thing here there is no activity happened after publish. Looks like event totally ignored. If I use test receiver from vendor example it is can't catch any events. I don't receive any error message about wrong connection or like this. So how find reason of this behaviour and resolve this issue?

Comment: SendNewsEvent isn't part of the sample you referenced. Does the receiver have a handler implemented for the SendNewsEvent event?

Comment: you need to await `endpoint.Publish(news ).`